# filling a full page div, minus padding on each side

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div thats the full page with 30px of padding and an inner div that i just want to fill the room so i will have a kind of floating box, equal on all sides.

When i set the inner div width and height to 100%, it takes 100% of the page instead of the div minus padding.

HTML:

```
  <div class="fullscreen-page padding-container">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.fullscreen-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.padding-container{
  padding: 30px;
}

#inner {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltm43pax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard box model ([`box-sizing: content-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)) adds the padding to the current width height.

Remove the `width: 100%`, and `height: 100%` from `.fullscreen-page`, since you already get the width and height from the `absolute` position, and the `top/right/bottom/left` settings.

```css
.fullscreen-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.padding-container {
  padding: 30px;
}

#inner {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-page padding-container">
  <div id="inner">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Demo [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/v80y7f70/1/)

> Note: I believe `border-box` is the widely used value for
>   `box-sizing`. Since you need not to worry about padding effects your
>   actual width and height of your content. More you can read an article
>   [Here](https://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/)

Add this

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @RachelDockter Your Welcome :)